# Change DateTimePicker style on combobox selection fails

Tags: c++, c, winapi, combobox, datetimepicker

I am trying to change the style and date format of the [DateTimePicker control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726(v=vs.85).aspx) on combobox' `CBS_SELCHANGE` notification.

When user selects one option, datetime picker should have spin control and show only year. If user selects other options, style should be reset to short date style and date format should show date as `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDC_COMBO5:
        {
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELENDOK)  
            {
                int iSelected = ComboBox_GetCurSel((HWND)lParam);

                switch (i)
                {
                case 1:
                    {
                        DWORD_PTR dwStyle = 
                            GetWindowLongPtr(GetDlgItem(hDlg,
                               IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), GWL_STYLE);
                        // remove short date style
                        dwStyle &= ~DTS_SHORTDATEFORMAT;
                        // add spin control
                        dwStyle |= DTS_UPDOWN;
                        SetWindowLongPtr(GetDlgItem(hDlg,
                            IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);

                        // set date format
                        DateTime_SetFormat(GetDlgItem(hDlg,
                            IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), L"yyyy");
                    }
                    break;
                case -1:
                case 0:
                case 2:
                default:
                    {
                        DWORD_PTR dwStyle = 
                            GetWindowLongPtr(GetDlgItem(hDlg,
                                IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), GWL_STYLE);
                        // remove spin control
                        dwStyle &= ~DTS_UPDOWN;
                        // restore short date format
                        dwStyle |= DTS_SHORTDATEFORMAT;
                        SetWindowLongPtr(GetDlgItem(hDlg,
                            IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);

                        // set date format
                        DateTime_SetFormat(GetDlgItem(hDlg,
                            IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), L"dd'|'MM'|'yyyy");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break; 
        // other cases...
```

Format gets changed properly, but spin control doesn't get added at all.

Running through debugger, I can see that it goes through my code and throws no exceptions -> I went to `Debug->Exceptions` and checked everything under `Thrown`.

I work on Windows 7 x86, using Visual Studio 2013.

I am targeting XP onward.

Can you help me to fix my code so I can achieve desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain common control properties that can't be changed after the control is created. In this case, the date/time picker only looks at the `DTS_UPDOWN` style upon creation - if the bit is set when it processes `WM_CREATE` it then creates the child spin control.

In fact if you query the control's style bits using `GetWindowLong` after trying to change that style you'll see that it actively blocked the change - it won't let you change `DTS_UPDOWN` or `DTS_SHOWNONE` after creation.

Your options are either to destroy and recreate the control as needed, or to start with two different controls in the first place and switch between them using `ShowWindow`.